# Can't see EFS files when launching EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

I am using EFS as a storage solution. I mounted EFS on an instance and uploaded some files to it. When I mount the EFS on other instances I can see the files I uploaded, but when I add the EFS to an EC2 instance during launch, I cannot see the files.

What can be the issue ?

UPDATE : I ran `df -h` command and the result was

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        482M     0  482M   0% /dev
tmpfs           492M     0  492M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           492M  416K  492M   1% /run
tmpfs           492M     0  492M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/xvda1      8.0G  1.5G  6.6G  18% /
tmpfs            99M     0   99M   0% /run/user/1000
```

so the filesystem is not being mounted, I added it during launch using aws management console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you run df -h and verify that mount point you specific during instance launch is visible or not ?

Comment: posted a solution which talks about as to why you are not able to see your mount point, if it helps an upvote/acceptance would be appreciated so that it may help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

**You must have forgot to click on add user data which automatically adds script for efs mount points, generate a user data script used during the initial boot process to setup the EFS mounts, and persist them across reboots**

> click Add to User Data, which will generate a user data script used during the initial boot process to setup the EFS mounts, and persist them across reboots. Click Advanced Details to see the User Data generated by your file system selections.

For more details follow the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonEFS.html)
even this blogs talks about the same with screenshots to let you know what commands is added automatically **upon clicking on Add user data** https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/automate-mounting-amazon-efs-file-systems-from-the-ec2-launch-instance-wizard/

> you have 2 options to deal with this problem, either relaunch your instance and add user data or mount efs [manually](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/wt1-test.html#wt1-connect-install-nfs-client) by sshing into your instance using nfs client